# Update tabs from a tab's activity in a Android TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have a TabActivity and am going to have 3 or 4 tabs.

In TabA, I would like to have an ExpandableListView, which will list products. I would like TabC to act as a sort of "shopping cart", probably with a ListView of itself.

Is there a way to interact with the TabHost from the Activity? I would like to be able to click a button inside of TabA and have it update and switch to TabC. Is this possible? Can I get the Tab's activities call its parents methods?

Answer (score 16):

If you implement your tabs as views, rather than individual activities, this would be far simpler, run faster, take up less memory, and be a better solution IMHO.

That being said, in the Tab A `Activity`, call `getParent()` to get at the `TabActivity`. Then, you can use the methods pointed out by disretrospect.

Comment: +1 for the getParent() tip - although I do not understand the recommendation to use views instead of activities. I prefer activities to seperate the life cycles and also to seperate the code belonging to each tab.

Comment: @K. Claszen: "to seperate the life cycles" -- their lifecycles aren't separate. "also to seperate the code belonging to each tab" -- code separation in the form of Java class files has been around for 15 years. You do not need to use separate activities for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I observe, the activities lifecycle methods (onCreate, etc.) are only called if the associated tab is selected. And I like to be able to extend provided activities like `ExpandableListActivity` in a tab. However, both possibilities are provided and make sence depending on the requirement so I just wondered if there could be a general recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this code to change activity within a tab:

```
TabActivity parent = (TabActivity) getParent();
TabHost tabhost = parent.getTabHost();
tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call getTabHost from a TabActivity, see *[public TabHost getTabHost()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html#getTabHost%28%29)*.

See Tabhost for setCurrentTab, *[public void setCurrentTab(int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29)*.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Activity, use getParent() to get the TabActivity parent
2. In your TabActivity class, use getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabId) to get the Activity object
3. call the Activity object's method

Comment: how about getting the view in that Activity #3