# Tab UI in Android

Tags: android-webview, android, android-tabhost

I am an Android newbie and I really require your help.

I'd like to develop an app , which its UI is persisted of three Tabs, and the first one a WebView.

since I am not familiar with all the required building blocks, can anyone give me a sample? a guide how to do so?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The [Android API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) include several ([Tabs1 to Tabs2 sample files](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html)) examples. Install, try and have a look at them.

Regarding specifying the content of Tabs you have the possibilities to use Views or Activities. If you check some "Tab" related discussion here you will find that established users prefer to use Views (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945274/android-tabhost-update-tabs-from-tabs-activity/2945675#2945675)). I took the 'Activity' way so far and feel quite comfortable - but did not go to deep into pros and cons. My current point of view is that you have to decide on each special case and can't give a general recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

there is some tutorials on this page : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html