# Reload a single tab in a tabview after doing sync

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I have a five tab's all are individual activity, I want to reload one activity after doing Sync without tab view I have done

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

How to do in a tabview

Comment: have you tried using fragment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2945675/1168654

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restarting your activity declare the intialization things in a separate method. Then after sync just call that method to refresh your activity.